# Ubuntu 20.04 Disk Partition - Clean install replacing Windows 10

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

This is Ubuntu newbie
I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 replacing Windows 10 and erasing the disk.
How can I make disk partitions so as to separate OS and my data files?
Please help.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where in the filesystem should I store shared data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16521/where-in-the-filesystem-should-i-store-shared-data) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/460694/in-which-drive-my-data-is-getting-stored-in-ubuntu

Comment: Some more links. These show using two drives, but data partition(s) can be anywhere. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)